# Variables not registering in await function

Tags: api, async-await, next.js, notion-api

What I'm trying to accomplish here is use `req.body` to pass the query arguments and when it hits the endpoint, the variables should be used in the create function of the Notion API. Unfortunately, the variables are registering as undefined. I figure that it's a scope issue, but I can't figure out how to structure this.

```js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const {
    companyName,
    email,
    panelNames,
    tags,
    markers,
    inquiry
  } = req.body;

  try {
    await notion.pages
      .create({
        // use variables here
        companyName: companyName //says undefined
      }).then((result) => {
        res.
      })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

//Frontend code
const bodyQuery = {
  companyName: "Example",
  email: "example@gmail.com",
  ...
};

try {
  await fetch("/api/v1/submit", headers)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((res) => {
      setTests(res);
    });
} catch (e) {
  console.log("e:", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not pass `bodyRequest` to the request, so your backend can not receive data. Here's an example how to do it:

```js
await fetch('/api/v1/submit', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(bodyRequest)
  })
  .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
  })
  .then((res) => {
      setTests(res);
  });
```

And make sure your REST endpoint is `POST`. Hope it help!